# How to highlight all keywords in the sentence with Javascript in the JSP,HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

by using following statement, I was able to highlight the keywords in the sentence.
in jsp(html):

```
<P>Keywords</P>
 <div id="keywords">
 <% for (int i=0; i<  HighlightTermList.size();i++){ %>
   <span><%=HighlightTermList.get(i) %><br></span>  
          <%} %> 
</div>

<bar>

<P>Sentence</P>
<div id="sentences">

 <% for (int i=0; i<  SentenceList.size();i++){ %>

<%=SentenceList.get(i) %><br> 
          <%} %> 

</div>  
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">  
<script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>
```

in the javascript:

```
var sentences = document.querySelector('#sentences');
var keywords = document.querySelector('#keywords');
keywords.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    var target = event.target;
    var text = sentences.textContent;
    var regex = new RegExp('('+target.textContent+')', 'ig');
    text = text.replace(regex, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
    sentences.innerHTML = text;
}, false);
```

in css:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[image]

after I click the "good", the match results are shown.

however, all the sentence is displayed in one line. How to seprate the  sentence line by line and highlight the keywords?

So i was thinking about use the table, to store the keywords and sentence in the same table.

```
<table  border="1" width="960px" >
 <tr>

    <th>keywords</th>
    <th>sentence</th>
  </tr>

    <% for (int i=0; i<  HighlightTermList.size();i++){ %>

  <tr>   
      <td> 
        <div id="keywords"><span><%=HighlightTermList.get(i) %></span></div>
       </td>    
     <td>
    <div id="sentences"><%=SentenceList.get(i) %></div>    
     </td>
   <%} %> 

 </table>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">  
<script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>
```

The problem is the highlight function does not work if I use the table. Can anyone tell why it cannot work? How to improve that? Thanks.

Comment: You're searching for [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)

Comment: Because you don't have unique ID... So you selector doesn't work anymore.